# ¿Cómo puedo crear Mascara para número de teléfono usando AutoNumeric.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autonumeric

Necesito implementar la mascara siguiente:
(99) 9999-9999

```js
$("#telefono").autoNumeric('init',{aSep: ' ', dGroup: '4', mDec: '0'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/autoNumeric-1.9.41.js"></script>
Telefono [(99) 9999-9999]
<br/>
<input id="telefono" type="text"/>
```

Parece ser que no se puede con AutoNumeric.js, ¿Algún otro plugin que pueda utilizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
</script>


<input type="text" class="phone_with_ddd" maxlength="14">
```

Telefono [(99) 9999-9999]

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin